# C# Deserializing "2019/02/13 05:00 PST" to UTC DateTime from json

Tags: c#, json, timezone, deserialization, utc

I'm consuming external API which returns json response containing Date information in "2019/02/13 05:00 PST" format. The problem arises when Contract resolver is trying to convert the string into DateTime.

The environment I'm using us .NetCore 2.2

I'm unable to solve the problem.

The best solution I found is:
 DateTime.Parse("2019/02/13 05:00 PST".Replace("PST", "+2"))

But that just doesn't seem like good way to go about it.

Thank you for any and all help

Comment: Why not using JSON deserializer? It will convert it automatically into DateTime.

Comment: It doesn't It fails if I try to deserialize "2019/02/13 05:00 PST"  if I remove PST part everything seems fine. I also tried using DateTimeOffset  for deserialization but didn't help

Comment: If you have serialized a DateTime via JSON then it should be deserializable, but if you have serialized it as a string in the format you posted then you need to use some customized way like the one you used to deserialize it.

Comment: I'm consuming it from external API. I now that deserializer should handle it on it's own but it doesn't. If you for expample try something like DateTime.Parse("2019/02/13 05:00 PST") it with crash because default constructor parser is unable to figure out what is happening

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it correctly. The abbreviations of time zones are not unique. For example CST:

```
- China Standard Time (UTC+8)
- Central Standard Time (UTC-6)
- Cuba Standard Time (UTC-5)
```

So if your external API returns something like

```
"2019/02/13 05:00 CST"
```

What time zone you will expect?

If you 100% sure that the API returns only US timezones, then you can write a parcer only for US time zone abbreviations. And replace them the same way you did.

BUT:

1. Your example looks quite strange. PST has -8 offset, not +2.
2. Potentionally your code can work incorrectly even for US if the government of the US decide to change the offset for any time zone.